# Feel confused about EKEventStatus

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

Does anyone know the meaning of `EKEventStatus`? I have searched Apple's documents, but I still can't understand the meaning. I want to get the events which the status is not finished or undo in calendar database.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/EKEventStatus

```
EKEventStatusNone
The event has no status

Available in iOS 4.0 and later

EKEventStatusConfirmed
The event is confirmed

Available in iOS 4.0 and later

EKEventStatusTentative
The event is tentative

Available in iOS 4.0 and later

EKEventStatusCanceled
The event is canceled

Available in iOS 4.0 and later
```

Comment: Is there a particular method you are using that returns an `EKEventStatus`? Do you have some code you can show that is not working?

Comment: I am writing a app which can let user know how many undo events in their calendar and reminders. However, I don't know which method can I use to get this purpose? And I want to know what is "EKEventStatusNone", "EKEventStatusConfirmed", "EKEventStatusTentative", "EKEventStatusCanceled"

Comment: This should help you with the basics of implementing Calendars and Events: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of those fields corresponds to the STATUS property of an iCalendar VEVENT, as specified in [RFC 5545 section 3.8.1.11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.11).

In short they tell you whether a meeting has been confirmed, canceled etc. Depends on the context.